# How to run a variable series or javascript functions in node.js using async?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm using [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) with Node.js. It runs fine when I have a fixed number of functions to execute:

```
async.series([ 
    function(cb) { ...one ... },
    function(cb) { .. two ... },
], function(err, res) {
    ...done
});
```

But now I need to execute an arbitrary number of functions, depending on values in one array, and cannot figure how to pass the array elements:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, ... ];
var calls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    calls.push(function(cb) { 

        HOW TO PASS values[i] HERE? 

    });
}
async.series(calls, function(err, res) {
    ...done
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a closure:

```
var values = [1, 2, 3, ... ];
var calls = [];
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    calls.push((function(index) {
        return function(cb) {       
            // use values[index] here
        };
    })(i));
}
async.series(calls, function(err, res) {
    ...done
});
```

Answer (score 2):

That's just the common async-in-a-loop problem. You will need a closure for the value of `i`, in which the pushed function expression is declared. This can either be done with an IEFE as your loop body, or even easier with [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
 var calls = values.map(function closure(val, i) {
     return function(cb) {
         // use val and i here, which are bound to this execution of closure
     };
 });
```